# Expected behaviour for redux state on page change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a React app, using Redux & Redux Sagas.

Currently I have a fairly standard search page as in :

User enters value via form input, magic happens behind the scenes, an api is consumed and my redux store is populated with the results.

These results are then surfaced via the view layer.

Using React Router 4, if I then navigate away to another page, on returning to the search page, my previous results are still shown. I guess this is expected as my redux state still contains this data.

My Questions is should this state be cleared on navigate away? I am very new to Redux / React / React Router and am trying to understand if I have implemented this correctly or in fact unless I instruct the store to clear that state, it should persist.

**tl:dr**

Should a redux store be cleared if I navigate away from the page or is it ok to leave that data on the view?

Comment: you will need to clear the redux state on navigating away if you dont want to show the result later

Comment: It only depends on your requirements and the data been stored in the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using React Router 4, if I then navigate away to another page, on
>   returning to the search page, my previous results are still shown

In React & Redux epoch you web application is SPA, and tools like isomorphic `react-router-dom` helps with this task, including seamless SSR support for URL router.

Of course, you can use `react-router-redux` instead, and in this case navigation to different pages will appear as actions, so them can be catched in saga, and then load new initialstate for redux store.

Library and example can be found here: https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-router